# SDL Keypressing

Tags: c++, sdl, keypress

I am trying to make a program that will be able to detect key-presses with SDL.

My current code is a modified version of somebody elses (trying to get it to work before making my own version).

```
#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    //Start SDL
    if(0 != SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING)) {
            std::cout << "Well I'm screwed\n";
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    SDL_Surface* display;
    display = SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_DOUBLEBUF);
    SDL_Event event;
    bool running = true;
    std::cout << "Cake"; //Testing output (doesn't work)
    while(running) {
            std::cout << "Pie"; //Again, testing output and again doesn't work
            if(SDL_PollEvent(&event)) { //I have tried this is a while statement
                    switch(event.type) {
                            case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                                    std::cout << "Down\n"; // Have tried "<< std::endl" instead of "\n"
                                    break;
                            case SDL_KEYUP:
                                    std::cout << "Up\n";
                                    break;
                            case SDL_QUIT:
                                    running = false;
                                    break;
                            default:
                                    break;
                    }
            }
    }
    //Quit SDL
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

This code is supposed to detect any key-down/up and output it, but it doesn't output anything.

My ultimate goal is to make it detect the konami code and then do something.

I constantly update the code above making it identical to the one I am using (except with added comments of what people have suggested).

Also if it helps: `g++ -o myprogram.exe mysource.cpp -lmingw32 -lSDLmain -lSDL` is the command I am using to compile. (If you didn't figure it out from the command, I am running windows (7).)
No errors occur when compiling

I am getting now output whatsoever, which leads me to believe that my probs has nothing to do with the key-checking; however there is a chance that is incorrect.

Comment: You aren't getting much help because at face value this should be ok. Is this the *exact* code you are running? How are you testing it? What if you add some extra output? Say at the top of the `while` block and the top of the `if` block?

Comment: Are you on windows ? I can't remember if `"\n"` is enough to flush `cout` on windows, so maybe...?

Comment: This is the exact code, copy-paste (then change indentation or it looks odd). Testing by running and tapping/holding random keys on both windows. I added output in the places you suggested, nothing is outputted. Also tried removing the "\n"s but no change.

Comment: @Nbr44 Good point. There was an answer to that effect, but it was deleted. I had a feeling it's often line buffered, so tried a quick loop outputting a short line with a 1 second sleep, and it was definitely flushing every time, but that is Linux.

Comment: Why the downvote? For a first question it's pretty rare in that it includes the real code and a clear explanation of the problem! It's not the most interesting question, but still a legitimate one.

Comment: @Pyro can you try and change `std::cout << "Down\n"` to `std::cout << "Down" << std::endl` ?

Comment: @BoBTFish it was my answer initially, but I didn't see the `"\n"` that already was in the string. So out of doubt I turned that in a comment for the time being.

Comment: @Nbr44 Tried. Still absolutely no output

Comment: Try checking the `SDL_Init` return value. [Should be `-1` on error, `0` on success.](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_Init). Perhaps it can't be set up properly, and hence can't get input from the keyboard.

Comment: @Pyro I.e. add `if (0 != SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) ) { std::cout << "ARGH IT'S ALL BROKEN\n"; return EXIT_FAILURE; }`.

Comment: @Pyro In fact you may be able to get a useful error message out of SDL with [`SDL_GetError()`](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL-1.3/SDL_GetError) as well. So `std::cout << "ARGH IT'S ALL BROKEN: \"" << SDL_GetError() << "\"\n";`.

Comment: @BoBTFish I added for one without SDL_GetError(), and updated the code in my post; there was still no output. Please tell me if I was supposed to of done it a different way.

Comment: @Pyro To be honest I never had `SDL_Init()` fail when I've played with SDL, which is why it took me so long to realise you don't even check it. If it succeeds but still doesn't actually get any events I'm afraid I'm stumped.

Comment: @BoBTFish Well, thanks for trying. It seems my code is difficult to fix.

Comment: also try to check if the executable you are running is the updated one. Maybe you renamed this new one(exe) different from the old one. I have also encountered this same problem.

Comment: @mr5 Yeah I have done that before, but not this time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SDL By default redirects output to stdout.txt

Answer (score 3):

SDL needs a window to receive events.

Uncomment your `SDL_SetVideoMode()` call:

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) 
{
    if( 0 != SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) ) 
    {
        std::cout << "Well I'm screwed\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    SDL_Surface* display;
    display = SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_DOUBLEBUF);

    SDL_Event event;
    bool running = true;
    while(running) 
    {
        if(SDL_PollEvent(&event)) 
        {
            switch(event.type) 
            {
            case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                std::cout << "Down" << endl;
                break;
            case SDL_KEYUP:
                std::cout << "Up" << endl;
                break;
            case SDL_QUIT:
                running = false;
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I commented it because it didn't help and it just gave 2 windows; however after I discovered that SDL by default redirects outputs to stdout.txt I had to uncomment this for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You should query for all the SDL events in the loop, not just the first one. Try this one to check all the events:

```
while( SDL_PollEvent( &event ) ){
    ...
}
```

also you can try to update the screen in the loop with:

```
SDL_Flip( display );
```

Comment: Note that it *is* inside a `while(true)` (roughly) loop, so will (should) be called repeatedly. Also, the flip is irrelevant here. There is clearly nothing happening graphically.

Comment: @BoBTFish, maybe you are right. I remember that the events should get from hardware with a pump, or something. I don't know it SDL_PollEvent do it itself.

Answer (score 0):

hey there i think you should go to your ***"project properties"*** then ***"linker settings"*** and ***"Subsystem"*** then choose ***"Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)"***  Otherwise you can't see what you typed in cout and in visual studio you cant use 
 `#include"SDL/SDL.h"`  you should type `#include<SDL.h>`